# Clarification on the information in the closed question banner

Tags: support, closed-questions

I am a user with more than 3K reputation and have the privilege to vote to close or open.  Looking at closed questions, I have some questions of my own.

It seems like most of the information on closed questions is found in the [privileges page](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions),
but the questions I have are not addressed there.

I have also read the help centre articles on [reopen questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/reopen-questions) and [closed questions](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions)
but my questions are not addressed there either.

My questions:

1. For some questions, I can see who closed the question, but for others I cannot.  It is a small sample size, but it appears that I can see the users who voted to close someone else's question, but I cannot see the users who voted to close my own question.  If this is correct, what am I supposed to do with the information available?  What is the purpose of knowing who closed someone else's question?  Conversely, what is the purpose of withholding from me who closed my question?
2. In questions for which I can see who closed them, in the blue banner it says "(Viewable by the post author and users with the close/reopen votes privilege)".  What, exactly, is viewable?  The question itself?  The fact that it was closed?  The banner?  Who closed the question?  (The last is not true in my experience)
3. In questions for which I cannot see who closed them (my own questions?), in the blue banner it says, "(Private feedback for you)".  What exactly is the private feedback?  I do not see anything in the banner of my own question that I cannot also see in the banner of someone else's closed question - in fact, I see less.  So what is the "private" feedback?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. The different banners are:

What a user **without** close/reopen privilege sees on **another** user's post

[image]

What a user **without** close/reopen privilege sees on **their own** post

I don't know - I don't have any closed questions on any site where I don't have this privilege - anyone who does, please post a picture.

What a user **with** close/reopen privilege sees on **another** user's post

[image]

What a user **with** close/reopen privilege sees on **their own** post

[image]

So, yes, there are different banners and you are seeing the correct ones. As to why they are different, only the arcane programmers at SE know But as a guess - knowing who closed a question (and whether it was a single person with single vote close privilege or multiple users) is useful info BUT if it's your post AND you are the vindictive type then you might go on a revenge motivated downvoting spree.

2. That particular banner is viewable because other people see different banners. It's also not completely accurate since the post author actually sees a different banner.
3. That particular banner is the private feedback - its not much feedback I grant you.

Comment: There is some intent given in [this MSE post announcing the new banners](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339700/681403). I'm pretty sure <3k don't get the list of users on their own closed questions anymore (but I can't find that noted anywhere). If you need to find out who closed a post, it should always list them in the question's timeline.

Comment: @Someone_Evil's point on being able to check the timeline is likely worth including in this answer.